# Why does batch file for "Send To" to get all file names of a folder with space in path not work?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filenames

I need to get the names of all files within a folder to do a compare in Excel. I have this working and set up as a **Send To** feature. However, if the folder I right click on contains a space, it fails. Here is what I have:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set cp=%%x
chcp 1252>nul
set dirpath=%1
dir %dirpath% dir /b /a | sort > "%dirpath%\FolderContents.txt"
chcp %cp%>nul
exit
```

Why are the file names not written to `"Selected Folder\FolderContents.txt"` if folder path contains 1 or more spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in those few lines of batch code.

The line with command **DIR** contains the command twice.

As the last paragraph output after several pages on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window explains, a file/folder name (and other parameter strings) must be enclosed in double quotes if there is in name or path a **space** or one of the following characters: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

Therefore first argument of batch file on execution is enclosed in quotes if folder name contains a space. `set dirpath=%1` assigns the folder name **with the quotes** to the environment variable `dirpath`. This results on next line in `""C:\Folder With Space"\FolderContents.txt"` which can't be processed by command processor as expected by you.

A number left to redirection operator `>` could easily result in getting it interpreted as handle number. Although code page numbers are large enough to be not interpreted as handle number, it is better to have a space left to last redirection operator `>` in your code as `%cp%` is replaced by a code page number.

A really working and additionally simplified code for your task is:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set "cp=%%x"
chcp 1252 >nul
dir "%~f1" /A-D /B /ON >"%~f1\FolderContents.txt"
chcp %cp% >nul
exit
```

The command **DIR** outputs just

- the names of files because of option `/A-D`
- in bare format because of option `/B`
- ordered by name because of option `/ON`
- and without path because of not using option `/S` for getting a list with all subdirectories included.

`%~f1` is replaced by command processor by name of folder with **full** path **without** quotes.

Well, determining active code page of this and only this command process and restoring the code page before exiting entire command process is also not really needed in my point of view and therefore second and last but one line are also not necessary.

This variant of above writes the file names with path into the text file.

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 >nul
del "%~f1\FolderContents.txt" 2>nul
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~f1" /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    >>"%~f1\FolderContents.txt" echo %~f1\%%I
)
exit
```

The redirection operator `>>` is now left to command **echo** to avoid that a file name ending very unlikely with  `1`,  `2`, ... is interpreted as handle number. A separating space can't be used here as this space would be also written into the file as being taken by command **echo** which would result in a trailing space on each file name in text file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `chcp /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`

See also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry I lost sight of this.  I made your changes and it works great.  I am VERY new to Batch Commands, as you can probably tell already.  I do have an additional question.  I am using this to pull all of the File Names out of a folder and put them in a Spread Sheet for bulk processing.  A new need has risen where I would like to be able to run this on the Parent Folder, and have the command create a new file in each Child Folder.  Structure would look like this:

Bulk Processing (Only Sub-Folders - no files)
     Bulk_Process_Job_1
     Bulk_Process_Job_2
     ETC....

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `for /?`. You can read about `for /D %Variable IN (Set) DO Command`. With `Set` being `..\*` the loop body (single command or a block) would be executed for each subfolder of parent folder. Try this command with running in command prompt window `for /D %# in (..\*) do @echo %#` and in batch file use `%%#` and replace `@echo %#` by whatever you want.